# Rails: Unable to create a Global ID for Model without a model id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

I am getting the following error from a Rails app:

> URI::GID::MissingModelIdError in Treatment
>
> Unable to create a Global ID for Treatment without a model id.

```
globalid (0.4.1) lib/global_id/uri/gid.rb:167:in `validate_model_id'
globalid (0.4.1) lib/global_id/uri/gid.rb:151:in `set_model_components'
globalid (0.4.1) lib/global_id/uri/gid.rb:136:in `check_path'
/Users/josh/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/uri/generic.rb:819:in `path='
/Users/josh/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/uri/generic.rb:193:in `initialize'
/Users/josh/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/uri/generic.rb:138:in `new'
/Users/josh/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/uri/generic.rb:138:in `build'
globalid (0.4.1) lib/global_id/uri/gid.rb:92:in `build'
globalid (0.4.1) lib/global_id/uri/gid.rb:68:in `create'
globalid (0.4.1) lib/global_id/global_id.rb:15:in `create'
globalid (0.4.1) lib/global_id/identification.rb:8:in `to_global_id'
activestorage (0.1) lib/active_storage/attached/one.rb:5:in `attachment'
activestorage (0.1) lib/active_storage/attached/one.rb:13:in `attached?'
app/views/treatments/_form.html.erb:52:in `block in _app_views_treatments__form_html_erb___357661333339907035_70285432864960'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:39:in `block in capture'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:203:in `with_output_buffer'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:39:in `capture'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:450:in `form_for'
app/views/treatments/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_treatments__form_html_erb___357661333339907035_70285432864960'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:157:in `block in render'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:352:in `instrument_render_template'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:155:in `render'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:342:in `block in render_partial'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:42:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:41:in `instrument'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:331:in `render_partial'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:310:in `render'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:35:in `render'
app/views/treatments/new.html.erb:42:in `_app_views_treatments_new_html_erb___2682657173693281074_70285432951520'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:157:in `block in render'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:352:in `instrument_render_template'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:155:in `render'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:42:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:41:in `instrument'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:51:in `block in render_template'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:59:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:50:in `render_template'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:103:in `_render_template'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:52:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:141:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:24:in `render'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:36:in `render'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
/Users/josh/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:29:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:33:in `default_render'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `block in send_action'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `tap'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:186:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:131:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:252:in `process_action'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:22:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:124:in `process'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:189:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:253:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:49:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:31:in `serve'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `each'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `serve'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:844:in `call'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `catch'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/migration.rb:556:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:59:in `call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:30:in `block in call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `catch'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.1.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/server.rb:658:in `handle_request'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/server.rb:332:in `block in run'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:133:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

I am getting this error when I try to load either the `new` or `create` method.

```
def new
    @treatment = Treatment.new
end

def create
    @treatment = Treatment.create!(treatment_params)

    if @treatment.save
        redirect_to root_path, notice: "Treatment added successfully"
    else
        render 'new', notice: "Oh no, Zuber u silly man!"
    end
end
```

The error is generated by the Global ID gem

Seems to be a problem with the `@treatment` variable. When trying to use this in the view I get the error, but also when trying to save the data to the database.

The model looks like this (not sure why there are 6 separate images rather than many):

```
class Treatment < ApplicationRecord
    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :link, use: :slugged
    
    validates :speciality,:link,:price,:duration,:image, presence: true
    validates :content, presence: true, length: { minimum: 15}

    has_one_attached :image
    has_one_attached :image1
    has_one_attached :image2
    has_one_attached :image3
    has_one_attached :image4
    has_one_attached :image5
    has_one_attached :image6

end
```

And the schema:

```
create_table "treatments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "category"
    t.string "speciality"
    t.text "content"
    t.integer "price"
    t.string "duration"
    t.string "link"
    t.string "image"
    t.string "image1"
    t.string "image2"
    t.string "image3"
    t.string "image4"
    t.string "image5"
    t.string "image6"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "slug"
    t.index ["slug"], name: "index_treatments_on_slug", unique: true
  end
```

I'm pretty new to Rails and am looking at this on behalf of a friend who is even newer, and I don't know what he may or may not have done previously to cause the error.

I hope someone can help, after a couple of hours of searching I couldn't find anything helpful.

Thanks!

---

EDIT:

I think this is something to do with Active Storage, as if I try to use `@treatments.image.attached?` in the view I get an error, but if just `@treatments.image` is used there is no error.

Comment: look into your logs and post the complete stacktrace. here is an article that describes multiple debugging techniques to use in development http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/

Comment: These two actions look relatively normal, except that you probably don't need both a `create!` and a `save` in the `create` action. Can you share the `Treatment` model and its definition in schema.rb?

Comment: Thanks @phoet that's a useful article! I have added the trace above.

Comment: And the model and schema @Masondesu

Answer (score 0):

After realising that the app is in Rails 5.1.6, I decided to get rid of Active Storage in favour of the Paperclip gem. The error is no more!